# How to open a modal pop up after timer runs out?

Tags: javascript, timer, popup

I am a beginner in JavaScript and writing js code for a web application but stuck at one point.

I have a web page with a timer for 5 seconds and after the timer runs out I expect a modal to popup.

I have written the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/am96fL4e/3/):

```js
var count=-1; // initially -1 as we are having a delay of 1000ms

var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
    count=count+1;
    if (count >=6) //+1 than the req time as we have a delay of 1000ms
    {
        clearInterval(counter);
        /////////////what code should go here for the modal to pop up??///////////////////////
        return;
    }
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs"; // watch for spelling
}
```

I just want to know the code to enable the pop up after the timer runs out.

Comment: In your example are you using bootstrap?
You can use bootstrap modal plugin:
[link]http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is select the modal (with jQuery) and call its `modal()` method:

```
$("#myModal").modal();
```

That will invoke the modal. I've also modified your Fiddle to give you an example here: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/18h306r2/).

Comment: what if I do not want jquery?